# javax.mail.MessagingException in servlet

Tags: eclipse, servlets, jakarta-mail

In Eclipse, I created a class EmailSender.java to send an email using the javax.mail library.
In a tester class, Tester.java, I am able to create a EmailSender object and send an email

**Tester.java**

```
EmailSender emailS=new EmailSender();
emailS.eSend(emailTo,msg);
```

And it's working..emailTo receives msg as email.

But inside a servlet, FaireOffre.java, creating an EmailSender object is giving me errors..

**exception trace**

```
Apr 17, 2015 9:41:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Marking servlet faireOffre as unavailable
Apr 17, 2015 9:41:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet faireOffre
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.MessagingException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at com.hp.servlets.FaireOffre.<init>(FaireOffre.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:433)
...
```

Note that my Tester.java class, EmailSender.java class and FaireOffre.java (servlet) are in different packages.

How can I resolve these exceptions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solved my problem:
Go to "Project properties -> Deployment Assembly page".
I added the javax.mail jars under 'Source'